# How to get the shaders similar to ken sugimori original Pokémon style

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, color, shader-nodes

Ive been using blender for a while and im experimenting different art styles. As an anime/manga fan ive always loved the old school 90s art style. One particular is the original Pokémon art by ken sugirmori (Watercolor) shown here.

[image]

Im curious if anyone knows how to get a similar shader node to this? would anyone be kind enough to post a screenshot of how to get this shader in blender?

Many thanks.